# Bootstrap alignments

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm new to bootstrap. Here I'm not able to figure out how can I achieve this kind of layout alignment using bootstrap. I tried but not able to achieve this, can anybody help me to do this!

Here is, what I want to achieve:

[image]

Here, there are two boxes side by side, left box (green with text) and right box having youtube video. when you resize it, that green box should go to the top of video box like stack. The text inside the green box should be vertically and horizontally center aligned.

Comment: Always submit a query with code. We have no idea about what you have already.

Comment: Thanks @Singh, Here is the link:

https://jsfiddle.net/abhilash503001/p7r1phuc/

Comment: In this case, alignment of text is not proper

Answer (score 0):

You can use different CSS definitions for different window size.
Look here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp 
and here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries
and here (example matching your problem): http://learnlayout.com/media-queries.html

Comment: Thanks @zajonc, very useful links, I really appreciate your response...!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create that layout with bootstrap. You may need to write your own because bootstrap's grid adds gutters between columns by adding padding. You should be able to add a background color to a column, but the content does not touch the edge like in the video example you posted.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">Green box</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">Video</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Take a look at this [jsfiddle for an example](https://jsfiddle.net/d7eb4ega/).

Read through [Bootstrap's grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) if you would like to modify it.

Comment: Thanks @Jose Carrillo, but how can I align text in green box vertically and horizontally middle, if the green box height is 100px ??

Comment: That's a whole other question but there are plenty of blogs with a solution. I think you can find you answer here: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/